# JavaScript does not define a method within an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following situation:

```
var a = {
    b: function() {
        alert('hi');
    },
    c: [{m: this.b}]
};

alert(typeof a.c[0].m);
```

The output is "undefined". What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `this` keyword inside an object. In that case `this.b` is referring to something undefined which should be a property of `window`.

Read [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/), it is very useful to understand scopes.

In this case, you should declare your variable like this:

```
b = 't'; //note there is not keywork var, it is a window global variable
var a = {
    c: [{
        b: 'a',
        m: this.b //is 't'
    }],
    b: function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
};

alert(a.c[0].m); //will display 't'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because (assuming you are executing this in the context of a browser) `this` is `window` and you haven't defined `window.b`.

The value of `this` is determined by the way you execute the current function, not by an object literal.

MDN has [further reading about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

When the value for a.c[0].m is run, this doesn't refer to a, it refers to the entire scope.

If you want the behaviour you are after, you need to change it to:

```
var a = { b: function() { alert('hi'); }, c: [{}] };
a.c[0].m = a.b;
```